# Crystal report with c# main to sub report connection

Tags: .net, winforms, crystal-reports, dataset

Hello every body i have one trouble i have one report like this

[image]

Well what i am doing is 
Dataset 
 1. Country master table
 2. Event master table

USing dataset to display country and event both well every thing is working perfectly except what i want is
Based on country id events should be displayed here where i am stuck because i don't have very much hand on this one and also by googling i found some solution which doesn't work for me can any one provide me help one this thanks in advance

***[Updated]***

data is displayed fine but i want to display events fro each row based on country 
display in first row of subreport where country id =main report.country id this should be repeated in every row

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried to add the table 2 to subreport datasource? it should be somenthing like this

```
ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
report.Subreports["mySubReport.rpt"].SetDataSource(ds.Tables[1]);
or
report.Subreports[0].SetDataSource(ds.Tables[1]);
```

UPDATE

I think you can achieve it passing the contry id to the subreport with events. 
Right-click on the subreport object and choose Change SubReport Links, it will open this windows, from here from the available fields you select your id that refers to event table, I can imagine that's the CountryId, In the bottom part of the window leave the left part as it is, and on the right dropdown select the field to which you want to link you subreport, in your case it could be events.CountryId. 
In my example I used Customer as main report and Events as subreport

[image]

Comment: ;) I missed that part

Comment: I dont get you raphael can you provide any example?

Comment: I can post some screen shots, there is no code to write it's just a setting

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40157/discussion-between-dholakiyaankit-and-raphael)

Comment: I have done raphael i have problem in my dataset that is my relation ship fields does have string datatatyp but certainly your answer gives me ideas i am acception your answer as solutions thanks for time :)